# How should l fix my voice call network on samsung s9 plus

Tags: network-programming, call

I can't make a call,l can't buy data bundles on my simcard in samsung S9 plus,l need help

I tried turning on Airplane mode on and off,l resented my network settings and restated my phone,and still l didn't got anything